# meaning of "lay out" in the context of building

Tags: meaning

I'm conscious of the meaning of "lay out something" on a typical basis.

> to arrange in a pattern or design; to plan something by showing how its parts fit together

I have some difficulty understanding it [in this example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russell_Square)

> Following the demolition of Bedford House, Russell Square and Bedford Square were **laid out** in 1804.

Does "lay out" here mean the same thing as "build", or something else?

Comment: It's pretty much the same, though it could refer only to the first part, maybe designing and laying a foundation.

Comment: That's from the Wikipedia article on Russel Square. I believe it refers to the design and planning. Such projects don't get built in one year ("in 1804").

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you, @JackO'Flaherty. My wife and I honeymooned on Russell Square some 20 years ago. I know this is not a useful comment, but there you go. I had to thank you. -- and to your point, you must be right - it's referring to the design and planning phase.